# Does Facebook SDK for Unity support Standalone builds?

Tags: sdk, unity-game-engine

It seems that the facebook SDK for Unity 3D only works for web player builds. Does it support Standalone Builds?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook SDK is currently supported for iOS, Android and the Facebook Canvas.

We are always welcome to feedback on what other platforms that developers would like to see this on!

Comment: So no standalone correct? When I say standalone I mean, windows, mac OSX and Linux executables

Comment: Desktop support would be welcome. My game will be released on web, Android and iOS, what can I use to get Facebook support for my desktop game?

Comment: You could try looking into Facebook Connect for your desktop game.  Sorry, I don't know much outside the Facebook Unity SDK.

Comment: What about web player without Facebook Canvas? Think deploying the game in a game portal or an advergame in the client's site. Those are common scenarios for game developers.

Comment: Currently the webplayer target is only support through Facebook Canvas and will not work outside of it.